# Reading twice an InputStream throws IOException

Tags: java

I'm facing a problem, can someone tell me how to void this? It throws up an "java.io.IOException: Stream closed". I know where my mistake is but I dont know how to fix it. BufferedReader closes from the first function and I dont know how to reset it within the second one. Function should format text from one text file to another with tabs. Thank you

```
import java.io.*;

public class TestClass {

private void prosekStudentKRS(FileReader fr) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    int j = 0, vksum = 0;
    try{
        reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
        reader.readLine();
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            int sum = 0;
            j++;
            String[] niza = line.split(",");
            for(int i = 1; i < niza.length; i ++) {
                sum+=Integer.parseInt(niza[i]);
            }
            vksum += Integer.parseInt(niza[1]);
            System.out.printf("Student %d ima prosek %.2f\n", j, (float) sum / 3);
        }


        System.out.println("Prosek po KRS: " + vksum / (double) j);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(reader != null) {
            reader.close();
        }
    }

}

private void TSV(FileReader fr, FileWriter fw) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader reader = null;
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
        writer = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] niza = line.split(",");
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i = 0; i < niza.length; i ++) {
                sb.append(niza[i] + "\t");
            }
            writer.write(sb.toString());
            writer.newLine();
            writer.flush();
        }


    } finally {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.close();

        if(writer != null) {
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\pc\\IdeaProjects\\LabOS01\\rezultaticsv.txt");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\pc\\IdeaProjects\\LabOS01\\rezultatitsv.txt");
    TestClass filetest = new TestClass();

    filetest.prosekStudentKRS(fr);
    filetest.TSV(fr, fw);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the error message contain which line caused the error?

Comment: It does not, but it's obvious. If you call prosekStudentKRS without/or with TSV, prosekStudentKRS works properly but TSV throws this error. If you comment prosekStudentKRS, TSV works properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either create two distinct `FileReader` objects and pass a different to each method.
Otherwise you can also create a `BufferedReader` from the  `FileReader`  before invoking the methods, pass it to the first method, reset it with the `reset()` method and pass it to the other method.

As alternative if the file is not too big, you could store in a `List<String>` each line read rather than reading again the file.
It would be more efficient.

Comment: That worked, and thanks for your advice. I was thinking the same, will try it out. Thank you once again

Comment: @Anthino Russo You are welcome :) Good ! I added another alternative.